# Difference in Ada remainder operators?

Tags: operators, ada

So, I know that Ada offers two remainder operators, `rem` and `mod`, but what exactly is the difference between them? I was able to find [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Operators), but I'm not sure I'm fully grasping the difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no difference between `A mod B` and `A rem B` if `A` is nonnegative and `B` is positive.  If `A` is negative and `B` is positive, `mod` gives you the true mathematical modulo operation; thus, for example, if B is 5, here are the results of `A mod 5` and `A rem 5` for values of `A`:

```
A       = -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
A mod 5 =   0  1  2  3  4  0  1  2  3  4  0  1  2  3  4  0  1  2  3 
A rem 5 =   0 -4 -3 -2 -1  0 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  0  1  2  3
```

Note the pattern in the `A mod 5` results.
`rem` corresponds to the way the `%` operator works in C-style languages (but not Python or Ruby, apparently).  It may be faster on some processors.  If you have to deal with negative values for `A`, my hunch is that `mod` is much more likely to be useful, but there may be some uses for `rem` also.  I don't think there's much use at all for `mod` or `rem` with a negative right-hand operand, so I wouldn't worry too much about the definition.

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [LRM](http://archive.adaic.com/standards/83lrm/html/lrm-04-05.html#4.5.5), the difference is which operand's sign is associated with the result.

> Integer division and remainder are defined by the relation
>           A = (A/B)*B + (A rem B) 
>       where (A rem B) has the sign of A and an absolute value less than the absolute value of B. Integer division satisfies the identity

```
    (-A)/B = -(A/B) = A/(-B)
```

> The result of the modulus operation is such that (A mod B) has the sign of B and an absolute value less than the absolute value of B; in addition, for some integer value N, this result must satisfy the relation

```
    A = B*N + (A mod B)
```